# Accessing audio via function

Tags: function, audio, unity-game-engine, unityscript

In Unityscript I'm able to directly access audio data. In the scene, I have a gameobject with a sound file and a script attached to it.

```
var mySound : AudioClip;
mySound = audio.clip;
var mySoundChannels = mySound.channels;
```

However, I'm having problems trying to access audio data via a function:

```
#pragma strict
var mySound : AudioClip;

function Start()
{
    mySound = audio.clip;
    GetAudio(mySound);
}

function GetAudio(au)
{
    print ("Audio: " + (mySound === au));     // true
    //var mySoundChannels = mySound.channels; // works
    var mySoundChannels = au.channels;        // fails
    var stereoOrNot = (mySound.channels == 2 ? "stereo" : " mono"); //works
    print(stereoOrNot);
}
```

I thought I could access au.channels, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong I (apart from wanting to access audio indirectly)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a dynamic variable there, I'm not sure if the var mySoundChannels will be typed to an **AudioClip** or an **int**. If it is an AudioClip then it will fail because channels are read only. Try it with `int mySoundChannels = au.channels;`